# Gitlab ci Build job fails randomly with no changes to code on scheduled pipeline

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a scheduled pipeline that runs every night at 10PM UTC on a specific branch, `nightly-tests`. This pipeline has 2 jobs: `Build` and `Test`.

Over the 6 days, there has been no changes to this branch. However, the `Build` job has failed on day 2, 3, 4, and 6. Judging from the build output, the job is using old code from ~2 weeks ago.

I believe that the `Build` job on the scheduled pipeline is using build cache from a old `Build` job that failed on a different pipeline, but I can't prove this.

I even added `cache: []` to the `Build` job inorder to force the job to not use cache but the `Build` job still fails randomly.

What could I be doing wrong? I am more than happy to provide more info and context if needed. I have also left the pipeline config file for the scheduled pipeline below. Thank you!

```yaml
# This pipeline config is for scheduled tests. They run on their own scheduled pipeline and are separate from
# the C++ testing. This is required since gitlab can only schedule pipelines, and not specific jobs


default:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my-image:1.5.0
  # Cache build objects on each new branch to decrease build time
  cache:
    key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}
    paths:
      - build
  timeout: 10hr
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 day

stages:
  - Build
  - Test

Build:
  stage: Build
  cache: [] # Force this job to not use cache
  script:
    - cmake -E make_directory build
    - cd build && cmake -DOUTPUT_PATH_PREFIX=$(pwd) ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
    - cmake --build . --config Debug -- -j$(nproc)
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - "build"

.Integration Tests:
  stage: Integration Tests
  image: selenium-simulator-testing:latest
  services:
    - name: docker:20.10.16-dind
      alias: dockerhost
    - name: selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
      alias: chromehost
  needs:
    - job: Build
      artifacts: true
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://dockerhost:2375/
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    REPO_DIR: /builds/my-company/my-repo
  only:
    - nightly-tests
  tags:
    - simulator-e2e
  artifacts:
    when: always
    paths:
      - "${REPO_DIR}/integration_tests/test.log"
    reports:
      junit: "${REPO_DIR}/integration_tests/report.xml"
    expire_in: 3 day
  before_script:
    # move ci build output to from build/output/bin/debug to output/bin/debug
    - mkdir -p "${REPO_DIR}/output/bin/debug"
    - cp "${REPO_DIR}"/build/output/bin/debug/* "${REPO_DIR}/output/bin/debug/"
    # authenticate client docker container
    - mkdir -p "${HOME}"/.docker/
    - echo "${DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG}" > "${HOME}/.docker/config.json"


Test:
  extends:
    - .Integration Tests
  timeout: 10hr
  script:
    - cd "${REPO_DIR}/integration_tests/"
    - pytest --tb=short -vvv --junit-xml=./report.xml --retries 2 tests/**/*.py
```

### Output of a failed build job

- Notice the runner checks out the correct commit hash and the correct branch: `Checking out c00a529c as nightly-tests...`

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.0 (76984217)
  on my_runner txmYpxuv

Resolving secrets

Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 ...
Using locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy
Using docker image sha256:003c79621ebbbe51325dedee1b325fd001e2ae8b66fc364cd37ef0286c614e80 for registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env@sha256:c445d9c3509d08ffc7af8c49250e465075968798d58b042adfcc47d0aa2b3bb8 ...

Preparing environment
Running on runner-txmypxuv-project-26580821-concurrent-0 via 82ee14e459cc...

Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/my-company/my-repo/.git/
Checking out c00a529c as nightly-tests...
Removing build/

Skipping Git submodules setup

Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:003c79621ebbbe51325dedee1b325fd001e2ae8b66fc364cd37ef0286c614e80 for registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env@sha256:c445d9c3509d08ffc7af8c49250e465075968798d58b042adfcc47d0aa2b3bb8 ...
$ cmake -E make_directory build
$ cd build && cmake -DOUTPUT_PATH_PREFIX=$(pwd) ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

## CMAKE BUILD OUTPUT HERE! 

$ cmake --build . --config Debug -- -j$(nproc)

## CMAKE BUILD OUTPUT HERE! 

Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

### Output of a successful build job

- Notice the runner checks out the correct commit hash and the correct branch: `Checking out c00a529c as nightly-tests...`

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.1.0 (76984217)
  on my_runner txmYpxuv

Resolving secrets

Preparing the "docker" executor
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 ...
Using locally found image version due to "if-not-present" pull policy
Using docker image sha256:003c79621ebbbe51325dedee1b325fd001e2ae8b66fc364cd37ef0286c614e80 for registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env@sha256:c445d9c3509d08ffc7af8c49250e465075968798d58b042adfcc47d0aa2b3bb8 ...

Preparing environment
Running on runner-txmypxuv-project-26580821-concurrent-0 via 82ee14e459cc...

Getting source from Git repository
Fetching changes with git depth set to 50...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /builds/my-company/my-repo/.git/
Checking out c00a529c as nightly-tests...
Removing build/

Skipping Git submodules setup

Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
Using docker image sha256:003c79621ebbbe51325dedee1b325fd001e2ae8b66fc364cd37ef0286c614e80 for registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env:1.5.0 with digest registry.gitlab.com/my-company/my-repo/my_build_env@sha256:c445d9c3509d08ffc7af8c49250e465075968798d58b042adfcc47d0aa2b3bb8 ...
$ cmake -E make_directory build
$ cd build && cmake -DOUTPUT_PATH_PREFIX=$(pwd) ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

## CMAKE BUILD OUTPUT HERE!

$ cmake --build . --config Debug -- -j$(nproc)

## CMAKE BUILD OUTPUT HERE!

Uploading artifacts for successful job
Uploading artifacts...
build: found 1922 matching files and directories
Uploading artifacts as "archive" to coordinator... 201 Created id=5649039263 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_1NtAa

Cleaning up project directory and file based variables

Job succeeded
```

Comment: I think I am needing a hint here, how about some log files or additional data?

Comment: @0074b60ae Im more than happy to provide more info/data. What log files or data do you need? The `Build` job uses cmake. However I cannot provide the output of the build due to propriety code. I can provide parts of the build job output that relate to gitlab and the build runner however

Comment: Not sure. Anything unrelated to proprietary code.

Comment: @0074b60ae I just added the pipeline logs for a successful and failed build job. You can see that both jobs checkout the same commit (`c00a529c`) on the same branch (`nightly-tests`). Please let me know if theres any other info i can provide!

Comment: - Same lines ```Using docker image sha256:003c...```  and ```Running on runner-txmypxuv-project-26...``` rule out environment differences between jobs as a cause.
- also same thing with the line ```Using docker image sha256:003c79621ebbbe5132...```
From the logs I am pretty sure that the issue is not with the build environment. Besides this, I have come up with nothing, sorry. It could be some non-determinism in the build process or conditional logic inside the Makefile, but I don't have access to these details, nor do I likely have the knowledge to understand or detect them.